# Order by score using Pagy pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently trying to order some ActiveRecord records by score. In my controller i have:

```
def index
    @pagy, @drivers = pagy(
        Driver.select(
            'drivers.*',
            '(drivers.no_races + drivers.no_poles + drivers.no_podiums + drivers.no_wins) AS score'
        ).reorder('drivers.score DESC'),
        page: params[:page],
        items: 16
    )
  end
```

I am using Pagy for the pagination. As the code shows, I do a query to select all drivers and then add together 3 columns in the table as 'score'. I then want to order by score going from high to low and show 16 records per page.
When the page loads it seems to order by driver id. I can't see anywhere else that i have an order by, but i did add reorder to override anything else.
Anyway for whatever reason i'm stuck with the wrong ordering. Any direction is appreciated :-)

Mockup - http://29qg.hatchboxapp.com/drivers

Comment: When creating an alias `AS score` it will not be available on the table, but is available as standalone name. Could you try `score DESC` instead of `drivers.score DESC`?

Comment: @3limin4t0r thanks for the comment. I now get ERROR: ORDER BY "score" is ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it was a simple error in the end. `"score" is ambiguous` because i was using score as an alias and i also had a column in the table called score.